# Apply Tax to the cart total based on product attribute value magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, event-observer, product-attribute, tax

I am applying custom tax for the cart item based on the product attribute value.

used below event for that.

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total">
        <plugin name="mbs_customtax_cart_item" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomTaxTotal" />
 </type>
```

Then **Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomTaxTotal.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CustomTaxTotal
{

private $logger;

private $_productloader;

private $_cart;
private $customTax = null;
protected $_resource;
protected $customerSession;
protected $_taxCalculation;
protected $_scopeConfig;
public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation $taxCalculation,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_taxCalculation = $taxCalculation;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

private function calculateCustomTaxForQuote()
{
    $taxRate = 0;
    $taxAmount = 0;
    $itemPrice = 0;
     if (is_null($this->customTax)) {
        $this->customTax = 0;            
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $itemsCollection = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        $quoteId = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getId();
        foreach ($itemsCollection as $items) {
            $productId = $items->getProductId();
            $binds_select_pod = array(
                'product_id'   => $productId,
                'quote_id'    => $quoteId
            );              
            $isPodExistQry = "select * from pod_temp_cart where quote_id = :quote_id && product_id = :product_id"; 
            $results_podexist = $connection->query($isPodExistQry,$binds_select_pod);
            $isPodExistRes = $results_podexist->fetchAll();
            
            if(isset($isPodExistRes) && count($isPodExistRes) > 0){
                $imageId = $isPodExistRes[0]['image_id'];
                $itemPrice = $isPodExistRes[0]['price'];
                $imageProductId = $this->getProductIdBySku($imageId);
                $this->logger->info('--imageProductId--'.$imageProductId);
                $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($imageProductId);
                $taxRate = $this->getRate($product);
                if($taxRate > 0){
                    $taxAmount += ($itemPrice * $taxRate)/100;
                }
            }
            if (isset($taxAmount) && $taxAmount !='' && $taxAmount != 0) {
               $this->customTax = $taxAmount;
            }
        }       
    } 
   $this->logger->info('--customTax--'.$this->customTax);
    return $this->customTax;
}
public function getRate($product){
    $productTaxClassId = $product->getTaxClassId();     
    $shippingAddress = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getDefaultShippingAddress();
    $countryCode =  (isset($shippingAddress['country_id']) && !empty($shippingAddress['country_id'])) ? $shippingAddress['country_id']:'GB';
    $rate = $this->_taxCalculation->getRate(
        new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'country_id' => $countryCode,
                'customer_class_id' => $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('tax/classes/default_customer_tax_class'),
                'product_class_id' => $productTaxClassId
            ]
        )
    );
    return $rate;
}

public function beforeAddTotalAmount(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $subject,
    $code,
    $amount
) {
    if ($code == 'tax') {
        $amount += $this->calculateCustomTaxForQuote();
    }
    return [$code, $amount];
}

public function beforeAddBaseTotalAmount(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $subject,
    $code,
    $amount
) {
    if ($code =='tax') {
        $amount += $this->calculateCustomTaxForQuote();
    }

    return [$code, $amount];
}
public function getConnection(){
    return $this->_resource->getConnection();
}
public function getProductIdBySku($sku) {
    $product = $this->_productloader->create();
    $product->load($product->getIdBySku($sku));
    $productId = $product->getId();
    return $productId;
}
```

}

The event is firing but the Tax is not getting applied,
I am getting Message: Infinite loop detected,in exception, can not place the order

from the suggested answer I am facing different issue.

https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/taxadditionaladjustment/src/master

from the above answer i am getting the below error and i can't place the order.

> Message: Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the looping path

can anyone help me on this issue please? Thank you for the support!!

Comment: Do you want to apply fixed tax amount OR need to change tax percentage rate ?

Comment: Yes @pawan, need to apply percentage basis

Comment: It seem like you want to have a custom fee base on percentage basis NOT a tax

Comment: @TuyenNguyen, No I have to apply tax programmatically,for the specific product

Answer (score 1):

In the code below, I have reused your code and I have the tax adjusted in the cart as expected. I have also a possible improvement (optimisation that is to give you) but for now, I am trying to provide you the solution that reuses your code so that you can apply it very easily. If you need some optimisation tips, I can post the details later.

> Mbs/TaxAdditionalAdjustment/etc/di.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total">
            <plugin name="mbs_customtax_cart_item" type="Mbs\TaxAdditionalAdjustment\Plugin\CustomTaxTotal" />
        </type>     
    </config>
```

> Mbs/TaxAdditionalAdjustment/Plugin/CustomTaxTotal.php

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\TaxAdditionalAdjustment\Plugin;

class CustomTaxTotal
{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    private $_productloader;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    private $_cart;

    private $customTax = null;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
    }

    private function calculateCustomTaxForQuote()
    {
        return 6;
        if (is_null($this->customTax)) {
            $this->customTax = 0;
            /** @var Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total */
            $this->logger->info('--total--');

            // retrieve quote items collection
            $itemsCollection = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
            $isDeliverable = [];
            foreach ($itemsCollection as $items) {
                $productId = $items->getProductId();
                $this->logger->info('--itemIds--' . $productId);
                $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($productId);
                $deliveryProduct = $product->getIsDelivery();
                if ($deliveryProduct) {
                    $isDeliverable[] = $productId;
                }
            }
            if (count($isDeliverable) > 0) {
                $this->logger->info('--inside--');
                $this->customTax =6;
            }
        }

        return $this->customTax;
    }

    public function beforeAddTotalAmount(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $subject,
        $code,
        $amount
    ) {
        if ($code =='tax') {
            $amount += $this->calculateCustomTaxForQuote();
        }

        return [$code, $amount];
    }

    public function beforeAddBaseTotalAmount(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $subject,
        $code,
        $amount
    ) {
        if ($code =='tax') {
            $amount += $this->calculateCustomTaxForQuote();
        }

        return [$code, $amount];
    }
}
```

I also have a module available at https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/taxadditionaladjustment/src/master/

this module pretty much is the answer from above within a module that uses your extra table

Comment: okay thank you @Herve, let me try your answer

Comment: @jafarpinjar are you able to provide feedback?

Comment: hi @Herve, i tested this, its not working, the plugin itself not firing

Comment: Now the plugin is fired, but i am getting Message: Infinite loop detected,in exception, could not place the order

Comment: can you please update me, i will update my question here

Comment: step 1: try to comment the code as per my updates on my answer and verify if the loop issue is not there anymore. step 2: once the loop issue has gone, I will provide change for the function calculateCustomTaxForQuote

Comment: okay sure, will try it now

Comment: yes its gone, but tax not applied, now i can able to place order without any loop error, please check my updated question

Comment: great, step3: change calculateCustomTaxForQuote to return 6 right away as per my last update and then do let me know if the tax is updated

Comment: please see my updated question, I am not returning  6 from the function, its dynamic, or for testing can i use like that?

Comment: at the moment, I am trying to verify if we are able to come up with a working solution to update the VAT. Now, of course, the value will need to be dynamic but first we have to check step 3..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109376/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-herve-tribouilloy).

Comment: tried your answer, but i am getting like this error, :getProductWithExternalData() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection,

Comment: hi @Herve please confirm why the model file is created here? can we write the same function in Plugin file?

Comment: yes, I have delegated to a model for the sake of simpler files but you can merge all my code in one plugin. The main purpose of my change is to have all your data coming out of 1 query and that seems to remove the loop. But also, one query rather than many will be a lot faster

Comment: hi @Herve I could solve the error, but still have infinite loop issue,please hep me on that

Comment: ok, can you send me your external table dump and update your code?

Comment: I have used your updated code, but still the infinite loop error is not removed, can you please update the code

Comment: i can not place the orders due to that error

Comment: please update me the working solution, Thanks

Comment: can't do much for you as I can't replicate your issue on my local, best of luck

Comment: hi @Herve, can you share your website link, will replicate the issue for you

Comment: it is my local site and therefore I have no public url

Comment: can you please share your email id or skype id, will share my website url and show you the issue

Comment: give me your email and I'll add you on a slack channel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109689/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-herve-tribouilloy).

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the collect() method. The below code works for me.

```
public function collect(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
) {
    
    $this->clearValues($total);
    if (!$shippingAssignment->getItems()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $x= $quote->getItems();
    if (isset($x)) {
        foreach ($x as $item) {
            $g = $item;
            $y = $item->getSku();
            $y = $item->getProductId();
        }
    }
    
    $baseTaxDetails = $this->getQuoteTaxDetails($shippingAssignment, $total, true);
    $taxDetails = $this->getQuoteTaxDetails($shippingAssignment, $total, false);

    //Populate address and items with tax calculation results
    $itemsByType = $this->organizeItemTaxDetailsByType($taxDetails, $baseTaxDetails);
    if (isset($itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_PRODUCT])) {
        $this->processProductItems($shippingAssignment, $itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_PRODUCT], $total);
    }

    if (isset($itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING])) {
        $shippingTaxDetails = $itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING][self::ITEM_CODE_SHIPPING][self::KEY_ITEM];
        $baseShippingTaxDetails =
            $itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING][self::ITEM_CODE_SHIPPING][self::KEY_BASE_ITEM];
        $this->processShippingTaxInfo($shippingAssignment, $total, $shippingTaxDetails, $baseShippingTaxDetails);
    }

    //Process taxable items that are not product or shipping
    $this->processExtraTaxables($total, $itemsByType);

   $total->setTaxAmount(2000);
   $total->setGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal()+2000);
   
    //Save applied taxes for each item and the quote in aggregation
    $this->processAppliedTaxes($total, $shippingAssignment, $itemsByType);

    if ($this->includeExtraTax()) {
        $total->addTotalAmount('extra_tax', $total->getExtraTaxAmount());
        $total->addBaseTotalAmount('extra_tax', $total->getBaseExtraTaxAmount());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

preference class

```
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax" type="BA\Vertex\Rewrite\Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax"/>
```

[image]